# Passing variable back to page with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page (form.php) that uses ajax to post some form data to a page (insert.php) which is then inserted into a mysql database.

I now want to be able to do a simple equation on insert.php and return the result as a variable back to form.php. Can anyone tell me how I return $variable back to form.php as a variable that I can then use?

Form.php

```
//Stripped down for ease of reading
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#message").hide();
        $("#submitButtonId").on("click",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var formdata = $(this.form).serialize();
            $.post('insert.php', formdata,
                function(data){
                    $("#message").html(data);
                    $("#message").fadeIn(500);
                    return false;
                });
        });
</script>


//The Form
<form class="form-inline" action="" id="myform" form="" method="post">

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="bill_cost"></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input id="bill_cost" name="bill_cost" type="text"
                   placeholder="Bill Cost" class="form-control input-lg" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit1"></label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button id="submitButtonId" name="submit1"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>

<div id="message">
```

insert.php

```
<?php
//Connection script would be here

$bill_cost=$_POST['bill_cost'];

//Insert into Database

$stmt = $db_conx->prepare('INSERT INTO mytable  set bill_cost=?);
$stmt->bind_param('s',$bill_cost);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt){

//Count Rows
$sql="SELECT bill_cost FROM mytable";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($query);

  //Do some maths (for example )

  $variable=$rowcount/100

  //echo message BUT how to send it as a variable?

  echo "<h1>Answer is ".$variable."</h1>";
  }

else{ echo "An error occurred!"; }
?>
```

Comment: Use `json` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send data which shall be parsed by your script, you should send your data as `json`. Sent every output as `json`, even the errors. For that you will have to send the `content-type` header. E.g:

```
// sending output
header('Content-Type: text/json');
echo json_encode(array("my_var" => "This is the content of the var"));
```

or sending an error:

```
// or sending error
header('Content-Type: text/json');
echo json_encode(array("error" => "This is my error"));
```

On the client side you can use `$.getJSON` ([Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)) to automatically parse the response as `json`:

```
// send request and get response
$.getJSON("insert.php", formdata, function(data) {
  // check for errors
  if (typeof data["error"] == "undefined") {
    // check if my_var is set?
    if (typeof data["my_var"] != "undefined") {
      // use data["my_var"]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added the header code to insert.php and I can now see the response"{"my_var":"hello"}" into the firebug console but I can't figure out how to get that variable. How do I get it? Many thanks,

Comment: @JulianJ: I updated the answer to show an example of how to use the JSON.

Comment: @JulianJ: Please mark this answer as the accepted one if it helped you. Otherwise it would be nice if you'd explain why it did not help you.